# Word boundaries RegEx in Teradata

Tags: regex, teradata

Consider the 2 strings and I am trying to find a match for the surname `ng` and ignore other words such as `string, working, laughing`:

```
t1 = "Strings are fun"
t2 = "Andrew ng is great"
```

In Python, I can use word boundaries such as:

```
> re.findall('\bnb\b, t1)
> []
> re.findall('\bnb\b, t2)
> ng
```

How do i replicate `\b` in Teradata so that
`SELECT REGEXP_SIMILAR(t1, pattern, 'i')` returns `0`
&
`SELECT REGEXP_SIMILAR(t2, pattern, 'i')` returns `1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teradata RegExes are PCRE based and support `\b`, but RegExp_Similar requires a full match, you need to add `.*`:

```
select 'Andrew ng is great' as s
   ,regexp_similar(s,'.*\bng\b.*')       -- 1
   ,regexp_substr(s,'\bng\b', 1, 1, 'i') -- ng


select 'Strings are fun' as s
   ,regexp_similar(s,'.*\bng\b.*')       -- 0
   ,regexp_substr(s,'\bng\b', 1, 1, 'i') -- NULL
```